# Preencher combobox, e pegar value menber vb.net e mysql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, vb.net, combobox

Estou precisando preencher um combobox com meu banco mysql, e depois pegar o value menber para inserir no banco de dados

Att. Estou precisando de auxilio de uma pessoa que sabe de visual basic.net , estou com um sistema, para uma empresa que trabalho de software, onde estou fazendo um sistema por fora para meu patrão, a empresa retira mensalmente cerca de 100 mil, e desses ganho ganhamos valores de comissão para cada venda, e fora o salario fixo, porém a empresa tem porte para ganhar mais, porém o sistema que eles comercializam está meio ruim, cheio de problemas, caso alguém queira ajudar, entre em contato 31 9 96508625 (whatsapp)

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, você vai preencher a grid com o exemplo abaixo:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT IdAlimento, IdTipoAlimento, NomeTipoAlimento FROM muscle.tb_alimentos "

Dim dt As Object = DAL.AcessoBD.ExecutarComando(sql, CommandType.Text, 
Nothing, DAL.AcessoBD.TipoDeComando.ExecuteDataSet)

For intCount As Integer = dt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
     Me.grdAlimento.Rows.Add(dt.Tables(0).Rows(intCount)("IdAlimento"), dt.Tables(0).Rows(intCount)("IdTipoAlimento"), intCount2, dt.Tables(0).Rows(intCount)("NomeAlimento"))
     intCount2 = intCount2 + 1
Next
```

e para pegar o valor do datagridview segue exemplo abaixo:

```
var intIdAlimento as Integer = grdAlimento.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```